# Expanding Sets into Simpler Forms

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How many numbers between 1 and 100 are  a multiple of 2, not a multiple of 3 and not a multiple of 5.

Let $A=$ amount of #'s multiple by 2

$B=$ amount of #'s multiple by 3

$C=$ amount of #'s multiple by 5

I am trying to find the syntactical structure of this question so I could solve it easily. I understand I can write all the numbers and cross them out one-by one but using Boolean to simply the problem. 
The problem can be reworded in Boolean as:

$$A \cap \neg B \cap \neg C = A + \neg B + \neg C-(A\cap\neg B)-(A\cap\neg C)-(\neg B\cap\neg C)+(A\cup\neg B\cup\neg C) $$

Is this equation valid to finding the answer? The problem is the formula is very cumbersome and also the components can be just as perplexing to find. Is there a way to break it into easily solvable chunks?

Can I reword this into $A \cap \neg B \cap \neg C=A\cap\neg (B\cup C)=A+(B\cup C)-(A\cup \neg (B\cup C))$. But the problem I encounter again is breaking up the 3rd term, $A\cup \neg (B\cup C)$, which is just as confounding.

Thank you for your patience and help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

The multiples of $2$ are $2,4,6,8,10,\ldots,98,100$ (assuming you intended $100$ to be included.  There are $50$ of them.  So subtract from $50$ the number of numbers in that set that are multiples of $3$ or $5$ (or both).  So how many of those $50$ are multiples of $3$ or $5$ (or both)?

By the inclusion-exclusion rule:
$$
(\text{number of multiples of 3})+(\text{number of multiples of 5})-(\text{number of multiples of 15})
$$
since multiples of both $3$ and $5$ are multiples of $15$.

Even numbers that are multiples of $3$ are multiples of $6$.

Even numbers that are multiples of $5$ are multiples of $10$.

Even numbers that are multiples of $15$ are multiples of $30$.

$6,12,18,24,\ldots,96$ are a list of $16$ numbers.

$10,20,30,\ldots,100$ are a list of $10$ numbers.

$30,60,90$ are a list of three numbers.

$16+10-3=23$.

That's what you need to subtract from $50$.